# ClassCastException when trying to get count of elements within a range in sorted set for rxjava2 client in redisson API

Tags: java, redis, rx-java2, redisson

I am getting a ClassCastException when trying to get the count of elements within the score range in a sorted set using the rxjava2 client in redisson.

code snippet:

```
var count = connectionManager.getRxClient().getScoredSortedSet(key).count(startScore, true, endScore, true).blockingGet();
```

I get the following exception on blockingGet() - java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in the module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

> redisson version - 3.13.6

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had raised this as a bug in GitHub and redisson team have fixed it. You can find the bug report [here](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/3259).